# no package provides libssl.so.10

Tags: linux, centos, centos5

I have some dependencies I need to resolve and I cannot:

```
[root@h tmp]# ldd /usr/lib64/collectd/mysql.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff9b070000)
        libmysqlclient_r.so.16 => not found
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00002b5d46a5d000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00002b5d46c71000)
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00002b5d46ea9000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b5d470c2000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b5d47345000)
        libssl.so.10 => not found
        libcrypto.so.10 => not found
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b5d47561000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b5d47765000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003b80c00000)
```

I've tried

```
[root@h tmp]# rpm --query --whatprovides libssl.so.10
no package provides libssl.so.10
```

It's centos 5.8

I also have:

```
[root@h ~]# yum install openssl
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.beyondhosting.net
 * epel: mirror.compevo.com
 * extras: yum.singlehop.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.team-cymru.org
 * updates: mirrors.loosefoot.com
Setting up Install Process
Package openssl-0.9.8e-27.el5_10.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package openssl-0.9.8e-27.el5_10.1.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS 5 (5.10 currently) packs libssl.so.6, not libssl.so.10 which is found in CentOS 6. The collectd-mysql package you installed might have been designed to be installed on CentOS 6 and not CentOS 5. For example this repository has both packages for CentOS 5 and CentOS 6: http://pkgs.repoforge.org/collectd/

Comment: collectd works fine, just the mysql plugin that is not. Is there a way I can install just the mysql plugin?

Comment: What package did you use to install collectd ? From the link I provided you can download only collectd-mysql corresponding to your system, if it's the same version as the collectd you have installed.

Comment: I did `yum install collectd` but mysql was not there, and I manually downloaded and placed the `so` file.